# How can I add the Entity Manager to a custom class or service?

Tags: doctrine-orm, symfony

In Symfony2, how can I go about adding Doctrine's entity manager to a custom class or service?

I have tried `$em = $this->get("doctrine.orm.entity_manager");`
and `$em = $this->getDoctrine()->getEntityManager();`

Both failed, which led me to try and extend the Controller class with my custom class/service, and that died in a giant ball of fire.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to inject the entity manager service into your custom service. Your service definition should look like this:

```
my.service.name:
  class:     my\class
  arguments: [ @doctrine.orm.default_entity_manager ]
```

Make sure that your service's `__construct` method takes the entity manager as an argument.

See the [Service Container chapter](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/service_container.html) for more info.

BTW, `$this->getDoctrine()` is a shortcut method that will only work in a class that extends `Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller`

Comment: In Symfony 2.3 I'm using "@doctrine.orm.entity_manager". Is there a difference between "@doctrine.orm.entity_manager" and "@doctrine.orm.default_entity_manager" ?

Answer (score 8):

You do *not* have to define your controller as a service in order to access the EntityManager. The `Controller::getDoctrine()` method mentioned above simply returns the Doctrine Registry by calling `$this->container->get('doctrine')` after checking that the doctrine service is actually available.

Simply make your custom class/controller extend `ContainerAware` and define a shortcut method like:

```
public function getEntityManager() {
    return $this->container->get('doctrine')->getEntityManager();
}
```

Note that it's `$this->container->get(..)` and not `$this->get(..)` in a class extending/implementing `ContainerAware`.

Comment: I get "Call to a member function get() on a non-object in ..." when using the above method.

Comment: are you extending ``ContainerAware``?

Comment: Where is ContainerAware?